# I need to calculate the bandgap voltage in terms of threshold voltage mismatch (circuit shown in figure). Does my equation look correct?

Tags: voltage, analog, cmos, voltage-reference

[image]

I computed the change in current due to threshold mismatch, in my assignment question they asked us to express the bandgap voltage due to delta Vth in terms of gm. Does this look equation look correct?

Answer (score 0):

Equations looks ok. We generally approximate the error as gmΔvth. The (Kn Δvth^2) term is usually ignored as it is small.

Edit: I have removed my comment about the sign.